# EFCore: Load value from function

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I've used the `FromSql()` function to load the results of a function alongside the data.  It works to some extent but am having trouble mapping it to my entity class.

```
            .return this.context.SomeTable
            .FromSql("SELECT *, " +
                     "[dbo].fn_RevisionNumber(CreatedOn, RevisionFamilyId) as RevisionNumber " +
                     "FROM Part")
            .Include(p => p.SomeOtherTable)
```

If I use `[NotMapped]` then it doesn't load the data (revision number is 0 whatever the SQL sends back) ...

```
    [NotMapped]
    public int RevisionNumber { get; set; }
```

Using this one it loads up the value, but fails when persisting ... looks like it tries to load the computed value after the persist.

```
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public int RevisionNumber { get; set; }
```

With no attribute it loads up but fails when persisting ... again looks like it tries to load the computed value after the persist.

```
    public int RevisionNumber { get; set; }
```

How should I mark this field to allow me to load it up, but not map?

Comment: If you load the item by the `FromSql` statement it'll read the computed value. Could you explain why you work with a persisted value *and* a computed value? Maybe the function should return the persisted value if it exists?

Comment: I just want the value from the function to load into RevisionNumber (I don't want that persisted)